# DateTimePicker Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datepicker, timepicker

I am trying to add a datetimepicker to rails.....
These are the instructions http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

---

So I have downloaded /jquery.datetimepicker.css and added it to my stylesheets folder…and downloaded jquery.js and /build/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js and added them to my javascripts folder….

Here is the code that I am using to try to display the date picker...

```
    <div class="col-md-6">
            <label>Start Time</label>
            <%= f.text_field :start_time, readonly: 'true', placeholder: 'Start Time', class: 'form-control' %>     
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label>End Time</label>
            <%= f.text_field :end_time, readonly: 'true', placeholder: 'End Time', class: 'form-control', disabled: 'true' %>       
        </div>
    </div>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/jquery.datetimepicker.css"/ >
<script src="/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/build/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>

jQuery('#reservation_start_time').datetimepicker();
```

Do you know what im doing wrong??? It is not showing up at all!

Thanks….

Barry

Comment: do you have console error?

Comment: You haven't told us what the problem is. I presume the datetimepicker isn't showing up when you click the date textfield? You should also post the actual code where you use the datetimepicker. Many people here will skip right over a question where the code is missing.

Comment: Sorry. I have edited it! thanks for the advice.... Its not showing up yea

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you got this resolved, but...

Your jquery code should really be in a separate js file and referenced in your application.js (since you're writing in rails). But, minimally, it should be within script tags at the bottom of the file, not after them.

Try this:

```
<script>
  $('#reservation_start_time').datetimepicker();
</script>
```